# TypeError: Invalid constructor input for ListRecommendationsRequest:

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a python script to retrieve the recommendations from the Google Api Recommender and getting this error: "TypeError: Invalid constructor input for ListRecommendationsRequest:"
My code looks like this:

```
from google.cloud import recommender


PROJECT = 'myproject'

LOCATION= 'us-east1'

RECOMMENDERS = [                                                                                                              
    # recommenders related with Commitments                                                                                   
    'google.compute.commitment.UsageCommitmentRecommender',                                                                   
    'google.cloudbilling.commitment.SpendBasedCommitmentRecommender',                                                         
    # recommenders related with clousql                                                                                       
    'google.cloudsql.instance.OutOfDiskRecommender',                                                                          
    'google.cloudsql.instance.IdleRecommender',                                                                               
    'google.cloudsql.instance.OverprovisionedRecommender',                                                                    
    # recommenders related with Compute                                                                                       
    'google.compute.image.IdleResourceRecommender',                                                                           
    'google.compute.address.IdleResourceRecommender',                                                                         
    'google.compute.disk.IdleResourceRecommender',                                                                            
    'google.compute.instance.IdleResourceRecommender',                                                                        
    'google.compute.instanceGroupManager.MachineTypeRecommender',                                                             
    'google.compute.instance.MachineTypeRecommender'                                                                          
]
client = recommender.RecommenderClient()             
parent = client.recommender_path(PROJECT, LOCATION, RECOMMENDERS[0])
client.list_recommendations(parent=parent)
  
for element in client.list_recommendations(parent):
    print(i)
```

Comment: The first argument of `list_recommendations` from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/recommender/latest/google.cloud.recommender_v1.services.recommender.RecommenderClient#google_cloud_recommender_v1_services_recommender_RecommenderClient_list_recommendations) should be a [`ListRecommendationsRequest`](https://cloud.google.com/recommender/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.recommender.v1#google.cloud.recommender.v1.ListRecommendationsRequest) object

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand can you elaborate a litle bit further?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the version 2.x of the [API](https://googleapis.dev/python/recommender/latest/index.html).

As you can see in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/recommender/latest/UPGRADING.html#method-calls), the new API version introduced a breaking change consisting in the use of requests objects to encapsulate the request information.

They provide the following example:

> Before:
>
> ```py
> from google.cloud import recommender
>
> client = recommender.RecommenderClient()
> name = client.insight_path('[PROJECT]', '[LOCATION]', '[INSIGHT_TYPE]', > '[INSIGHT]')
> etag = "my_etag"
> response = client.mark_insight_accepted(name=name, etag=etag)
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```py
> from google.cloud import recommender
>
> client = recommender.RecommenderClient()
> name = client.insight_path('[PROJECT]', '[LOCATION]', '[INSIGHT_TYPE]', '[INSIGHT]')
> etag = "my_etag"
> response = client.mark_insight_accepted(request={"name": name, "etag": etag})
> ```

Note the inclusion of the `request` parameter.

In your specific use case, `list_recommendations` has the following signature:

```py
async def list_recommendations(
        self,
        request: Union[recommender_service.ListRecommendationsRequest, dict] = None,
        *,
        parent: str = None,
        filter: str = None,
        retry: OptionalRetry = gapic_v1.method.DEFAULT,
        timeout: float = None,
        metadata: Sequence[Tuple[str, str]] = (),
    ) -> pagers.ListRecommendationsAsyncPager
```

Note how `request` is the first positional argument.

As a consequence, the error in your code is in this line:

```py
for element in client.list_recommendations(parent):
```

because the API is assuming `parent` as the `request` object.

To solve the problem, either provide the `parent` argument as a named argument as you are in fact doing:

```py
client.list_recommendations(parent=parent)
```

Or define the `request` parameter appropriately (a `dict` will do the trick):

```py
client.list_recommendations(request={"parent": parent})
```

Please, consider read the documentation about the different information you can provide for [`ListRecommendationsRequest`](https://googleapis.dev/python/recommender/latest/recommender_v1/types.html#google.cloud.recommender_v1.types.ListRecommendationsRequest).